# Why is "mythology" a tag on a Hinduism site?

Tags: discussion

Why do we have a tag named "mythology"? It implies the story isn't real, which is counter to the aims of Hinduism.

Comment: Mythology has another meaning which is "set of beliefs and stories associated with a religion." This can be used for stories or legends present in our scriptures. That is the way I use it. It doesn't mean a false story.

Comment: @NogShine Sure, but it has a negative connotation.

Comment: "which is counter to the aims of Hinduism..." - who get to decide what's the "aim" of Hinduism? You? Me? A bunch of devout Hindus? Scholars or Archaeologists who look for evidence of historicity of Ramayana and Mahabharata? Until that is settled, why use language claiming to represent all Hindus?