# Why hindu scriptures termed hindu mythology?

Tags: discussion

Please using the mythology term for scriptures should be stopped its all due maculay system of education, that hindu scriptures are termed like that, hindus themselves started using this words without konwing the gravity of the meaning of mythology.

Lets all take vow that not answer any question terming hindu mythology because its not false stories..

Comment: you question is about your concern mythology tag my question is about usage of term mythology for hindu scriptures

Comment: Lots of users hv raised their objections in the past abt the use of this tag. See this: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/new-community-consensus-on-use-of-mythology-tag and this in particular: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/why-is-mythology-a-tag-on-a-hinduism-site @prasannaragothaman

Comment: This is meta. Questions can be closed as duplicates if the same discussion needs to take place again and again. We don't repeat the same discussions again. There is tag excerpt for the tag. Also, lets take a vow we shall post questions after checking whether it was closed. No one are saying they are false stories. Mythology has different meanings too. If one wants to see only bad connotation, everything can be seen wrong. We are not a Hindu site to take vows.